# Sharing app apk during development. It sends an earlier version of the current app

Tags: android, apk, file-sharing, android-install-apk

I am developing an Android app. I noticed an error when sharing my apk with my friends. The version that is installed on their phones is an earlier version of the app installed on my phone(which I'm using as an android virtual device). What could be the error? Please Help.

Comment: Build > Clean Project and try again

Comment: how do you share it?

Comment: Try to update the project structure App version every time you make major change or add new features to your app .

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine - I am sharing the apk via Bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Build then select build apk then click on show in explore then send that apk.

[image]